# Capture packets from router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireshark

I wave a iBall Baton (iB-W4G311N) router,
it has only two Ethernet ports one for LAN and another for WAN, it also has WLAN.

A micro controller is connected to it via an Ethernet cable, I need to capture the communication between the micro and the router, using wireshark in my Win7 PC.

Nb: I also got a D-link network switch if its of any use.

Comment: Do you have a 2nd Ethernet card for your Win7 PC? Would be the easiest option.

Comment: yes, what should i do ?

Comment: Connect one ethernet card of the Win7 PC to the router, connect the other to the microcontroller. Configure the PC to forward raw packets in both directions (not sure to do this under Windows, maybe the google term "man in the middle" helps). Use Wireshark to capture the packets.

Comment: sorry for the delayed reply, but my second Ethernet card seems faulty, Can i do the "man on the middle" by bridging my wireless LAN with Ethernet Card and connecting to router via wifi ?